# How to join a 4th table which doesn't have common column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a 4 tables, detail_table, adders_table, form_table and summary_table
first 3 table have a common column piece_ID but 4th table summary_table is don't have a Piece_ID column but instead it has ID column which is present only in detail table not in address and form table
Now is there any way I can join all these 4 tables together?

(I have successfully join form, address and detail tables only remained is summary)
Below is the query with 3 tables and I got successful result from this.

```
    Select archive_address.PieceID, archive_adf_detail.Job_ID, prod_code, 
seq_number,process_date, seq_queue, addline1, addline2,addline3,addline4,addline5, archive_freeform.free_form1, archive_Free_Form2
from archive_Address join archive_adf_detail
on archive_address.PieceID = archive_adf_detail.F_key
join archive_freeform
on archive_address.PieceID = archive_freeform.PieceID
Where (archive_Address.addline1 like '%Cons%' 
or archive_Address.addline2 like '%Cons%' )
and archive_Address.pieceID like '%FB2K%'
order by addline1
```

**I am using below query to add 4th table with this**

```
Select archive_address.PieceID, archive_adf_detail.Job_ID, prod_code, job_summary.Status_Date,
seq_number,process_date, seq_queue, addline1, addline2,addline3,addline4,addline5, archive_freeform.free_form1, archive_freeform.Free_Form2
from archive_Address join archive_adf_detail
on archive_address.PieceID = archive_adf_detail.F_key
join archive_freeform
on archive_address.PieceID = archive_freeform.PieceID
join job_summary 
on archive_adf_detail.job_ID = job_summary.job_ID
Where (archive_Address.addline1 like '%Cons%' 
or archive_Address.addline2 like '%Cons%' )
and archive_Address.pieceID like '%FB2K%'
order by addline1
```

after executing the above I am getting below error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Invalid column name 'jobID'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ambiguous column name 'prod_code'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Ambiguous column name 'seq_number'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Ambiguous column name 'process_date'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'archive_Free_Form2'.
```

Please correct me if I am using incorrect syntax or it not possible to join 4th table like this
Thank you!

Comment: Yes . . . join the table using the common column.

Comment: But summary table doesn't have a common column which is there in rest 3 instead it has a column which is there only in detail table not in other 2, I am getting  an error while joining 4th table (summary table)

Comment: Please edit your question by adding the error message.  Also specify your database engine.

Comment: As Gordon said you should be able to join detail_table with summary_table on ID

Comment: Thank you for responding I have updated my question with queries that I am using, please correct me if I am not using correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Join tables based on the relationship that the query is expressing. Your joins are fine.

The error relates to the fact that the names of columns are not unique amongst the collection of tables (Ambiguous: having multiple meanings). You need to specify which table with the column name.

```
Select 
    archive_address.PieceID, 
    archive_Address.addline1,
    archive_Address.addline2,
    archive_Address.addline3,
    archive_Address.addline4,
    archive_Address.addline5,
    archive_adf_detail.prod_code,
    archive_adf_detail.seq_number,
    archive_adf_detail.process_date,
    archive_adf_detail.seq_queue,
    archive_freeform.Job_ID,
    archive_freeform.free_form1,
    archive_freeform.Free_Form2,
    job_summary.Status_Date
From archive_Address 
Join archive_adf_detail on archive_address.PieceID = archive_adf_detail.F_key
Join archive_freeform on archive_address.PieceID = archive_freeform.PieceID
Join job_summary on archive_freeform.job_ID = job_summary.job_ID
Where (archive_Address.addline1 like '%Cons%' or archive_Address.addline2 like '%Cons%' )
and archive_Address.pieceID like '%FB2K%'
Order by archive_Address.addline1
```

I'm not totally sure you've conveyed the schema, as the error messages in your question don't correspond to the second query. **You** need to have an understanding of what data is where, and which parts you want.

Comment: In addition to my first query I have added one column which is status_date and added a 4th table job_summary
join job_summary 
on archive_adf_detail.job_ID = job_summary.jobID

Comment: Which columns belong to which tables? I don't know your schema unless you tell me it.

Comment: sorry my bad 1st is the table name and then column names 

Archive_address 
(PieceID
Addline1
Addline2
Addline3
Addline4
Addline5),

archive_adf_detail
(PieceID
prod_code
seq_number
process_date
seq_queue),

archive_freeform
(PieceID
Job_ID
free_form1
Free_Form2),

job_summary 
(job_id
Satus_date)

Comment: You need to go back to the table definitions. E.g. does `archive_adf_detail` have an `F_key` column, or is it `PieceID`? For preference, edit it into the question, not a comment on an answer

Comment: The SSMS context menu "Script Table as..."->"Create" will give a table's definition. Copy those for all four tables

Comment: in archive_adf_detail F_key column  has same value as others have in pieceID

Comment: Query which you provided is working fine with little amendments, many thanks to you and now as per my understanding my query was not working because I didn't mention table name in front of every column right?

Comment: Well its only necessary for columns where the same name is used in more than one table in the join. It is never wrong to include the table name with each column